# In DDD, how do you handle a conceptual object that is somewhere between an Entity and a Value Object?

Tags: entity, domain-driven-design, value-objects

In your domain model, how do you treat a conceptual object that is somewhere between an Entity and a Value Object? I.e, it is not *small*; it has many attributes, but it also doesn't have any identity or meaning in-and-of itself (i.e. equality is based on attributes). Because it needs to have its attributes edited via the UI, I can't see how it can be made immutable--constantly being destroyed and recreated every time the user changes an attribute. Furthermore, this hybrid object is intended to *become* an entity of either one type or another, depending on its role in the system.

Example: a `Recipe` class. Its purpose is to encapsulate a set of instructions to be carried out by a machine. Two different recipe objects are equal if their collective instructions are identical. A Recipe is intended to take on two Entity roles in the system:

1. To be used in a `MasterSequence`, which is simply a list of Recipe
   objects that get executed in sequential order. In this case the
   Recipe would conceptually take on addition attributes such as
   `StepNumber` and `IsActive`. Each of these recipies now carries an
   identity (i.e. the Recipe in step 1 might have identical attributes
   to the one in step 2, but they are conceptually distinct).
2. A Recipe can be saved as a "Favorite Recipe" that is persisted in a
   favorites list. In this case the Recipe has no concept of StepNumber
   or IsActive, but rather, a simple `ID` that gives it its identity.

In either of these two roles, the UI needs to present a dialog box to edit the attributes of the underlying recipe. 
So should two entities be created, `SequencedRecipe` and `FavoriteRecipe` that act as wrappers to a Recipe object? And should the Recipe take on all the semantics of a Value Object, considering its size/complexity and need for editing?

Comment: I think you are on the right track with Sequenced and Favorite recipe. However, note that a VO may be mutable for performance concerns or that you may decide to model it as an entity for the same reason in specific circumstances, but don't do any premature optimizations.

Answer (score 2):

<s>I think you miss something in your ubiquitous language to distinguish between the *idea* of a recipe, i.e. its blueprint, and a real recipe as executed in a `MasterSequence`.</s>

The concept of Prototype (and [design pattern](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/prototype.html) by the same name) might be helpful here.

The `RecipePrototype` Entity would be able to spawn a new `Recipe` VO when needed. This VO would then be incorporated in the `MasterSequence` -- this way, if the original Recipe blueprint is changed, it won't affect existing `MasterSequences` using this recipe.

```java
public class RecipePrototype {

  // all your recipe fields here

  public Recipe spawnRecipe() {
    // copy yourself and return a new Recipe VO here
  }
}
```

A Favorite Recipe would simply be a reference to a `RecipePrototype` ID.

**Edit :** from the latest comments I now realize that `Recipes` contained in `MasterSequence` are not a specific kind of Recipe with a life of their own, and the original `Recipe` object is always what gets modified.

Thus, `Recipe` is clearly an Entity to me, there's no Value Object modification involved whatsoever.

This becomes a UI problem -- you just need to have two different ViewModels (`MasterSequenceRecipe` and `FavoriteRecipe`) for display but map to the same domain action in modification -- changing a `Recipe` entity.

Comment: Intriguing concept.. I'll have to chew on that one. Still though, the question remains: when the same UI dialog is editing either the RecipePrototype or the SequencedRecipe, how does that editing work if the Recipe is truly an immutable VO and constantly getting re-created on every property change?

Comment: @BCA What do you mean, how it works? Editing a VO is just a matter of replacing the whole VO by a new one. `sequencedRecipe.changeRecipe(new Recipe(...))`. If your screens are CRUD based and you want to make the editing process generic, for entities and VO's, then to modify a recipe prototype entity you might do something like `someRecipePrototype.mimic(new Recipe(...))` which would cause `someRecipePrototype` to change itself to be the same as the passed recipe.

Comment: @plalx or, have a shared ViewModel for both but a different controller method that maps it to either a `RecipePrototype` or a `Recipe` VO.

Comment: @BCA as plalx pointed out, "modifying" an immutable VO just means replacing it with a new version. Note that, while some languages like F# make it easy to derive a new immutable structure from an existing one (with the `with` keyword), you may have to write your own helpers to do that more elegantly than tedious field-to-field copy in other languages such as Java or C#.

Comment: @plalx, thanks for the insights. At this point I'm wondering if my premise is flawed, which is: using a View/ViewModel pair to edit the properties of the Recipe via databinding won't work because the underlying Model object (Recipe) is constantly changing. In my experience using the MVVM pattern it's always been a single, consistent model object that has its properties modified. Is there a way MVVM works with immutable VOs?

Comment: @guillaume31, please see comment above to plalx

Comment: @BCA in DDD, you don't data bind to your domain objects directly from the UI. There's an Application layer in between that initiates a business transaction and coordinates calls to Aggregates to change stuff.

Comment: @guillaume31, looks like I've got a lot of learning to do! Per chance, do you know of any good learning resources that deal with MVVM and DDD coexisting harmoniously? Seems like most resources these days assume a web/MVC context for architecture.

Answer (score 1):

I actually think Recipe is an entity because it sounds like it does have an identity in actuality.  You say if 2 recipes have the same values then they are the same.  Then you speak of editing those recipes in the UI.  How would you reference the recipe that got updated?  I doubt you would update any random recipe in the system that matches all the same attributes.  It sounds like you would need a recipe ID of some kind, since you do care *which* recipe was edited, even if the attributes happen to be the same.  Favorite recipe would simply reference the recipe by ID as well, or any other entity that had a recipe or sequence of recipes associated with it.

Comment: Exactly--a Recipe is only ever edited when it has the role of an entity (either a FavoriteRecipe or a SequencedRecipe). But in either case it's the underlying Recipe that gets edited

Comment: @BCA then I don't see why you don't just make Recipe a modifiable entity. I thought the underlying Recipe should remain unchanged, hence my answer, but if it is modified in all cases, why try to make it a VO ??

Comment: That's what I currently have (Recipe as a normal, mutable object). But in my trying to understand VOs, I'm being told that lack of identity should go hand-in-hand with immutability. And hence my original question: how is a view/viewmodel pair supposed to edit properties of an underlying object that keeps getting destroyed and recreated transparently?

Comment: Why wouldn't a Recipe have an identity if you can edit it and follow its changes over time ? Why should it be a Value Object ? My answer was based on the fact that the `Recipes` contained in `MasterSequence` were a distinct kind of object from the original `Recipe` and with a life of their own, but finally this doesn't seem to be the case. So no need for VO's any more, you can just refer to a Recipe by its ID...

Comment: @guillaume31 A Recipe itself has no identity. It only has an identity (and you follow its changes over time) when it takes on the role of FavoriteRecipe or of SequencedRecipe... and those 2 roles are completely different. It just so happens that their internal data structures are identical, and so it's natural to just factor out their similarities into a stand-alone data structure called Recipe.

Comment: This seems to contradict your earlier comment: *"it's the underlying Recipe that gets edited"*.